# Calculations with datetime index of Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a Pandas dataframe. The index of the dataframe is a datetime column namely "time".
How is it possible to call certain information like min() or max values of this index datetime column?
or how do I do a timedelta calculation?

The dataframe example:

```
                      Temperature   Humidity        Height
 time                                                                       
 2022-03-17 12:52:27   281.278408  74.551713    602.406738  
 2022-03-17 12:52:28   281.278408  74.551713    602.406738  
 2022-03-17 12:52:29   281.278408  74.551713    602.406738  
 2022-03-17 12:52:30   281.278408  74.551713    602.406738  
 2022-03-17 12:52:31   281.278408  74.551713    602.406738  
 ...                          ...        ...           ...  
 2022-03-17 14:28:07   220.382478   0.929040  26529.819649  
 2022-03-17 14:28:08   220.355416   0.933099  26534.843300  
 2022-03-17 14:28:09   220.327658   0.937137  26539.820942   
 2022-03-17 14:28:10   220.300062   0.941082  26544.776129   
 2022-03-17 14:28:11   220.272778   0.944972  26549.735739
```

What I principally aim at (just for illustration):

```
starttime = str(timedelta(seconds=int(df.time.min()))) +" UTC")
endtime = str(timedelta(seconds=int(df.time.max()))) +" UTC")
duration = endtime - starttime
```

Resulting (of course) in a AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'time'.

And using

```
starttime = str(timedelta(seconds=int(df.index.min()))) +" UTC")
```

results in a TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Timestamp'

Any hint for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
duration = (pd.Timedelta(str(df_1hz.index.time.max()))-
            pd.Timedelta(str(df_1hz.index.time.min())))
print (duration)
0 days 01:35:44
```

If there is same datetimes:

```
def f(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d} UTC').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds))

duration = f(df_1hz.index.max() - df_1hz.index.min())
print (duration)
01:35:44 UTC
```

Comment: @jezreael thank you for your help. In both solutions the resulting data type is a string. Without redefining it as datetime format: is there a possibility to keep the information that it is not a string type result?

Comment: @Swawa - First solution return `Timedelta`, second `string`. So not understand - there is no datetime in ouput.

Comment: @jezreael - Further I would like to calculate other time based on the result of "duration" - like `half_time = duration / 2` or `time_x = another_datetime + duration` what is not allowed with these results as they are string format. My question is: is there a possibility to keep its time information that I can perform these calculations?

Comment: @Swawa - Only way is use timedeltas - `duration = df_1hz.index.max() - df_1hz.index.min()` or `duration = (pd.Timedelta(str(df_1hz.index.time.max()))-
            pd.Timedelta(str(df_1hz.index.time.min())))`

Comment: @jezreael - ok, thank you very much -  so there is no possibility to have just a time information without date? When I perform the second solution date will be 1-1-1900 and the calculated time. If I use this result for further calculations the date stamp becomes wrong :-(

Comment: @Swawa - here is duration - timestaml called timedelta. So I cannot see datetimes in ouput. Only if convert duration to datetimes.

Comment: @jezreael - I am looking for something like `duration_s = (df_1hz.index.max()-df_1hz.index.min()).total_seconds()` followed by `startt = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(duration_s))` and `b_time = df_1hz.index.min() + startt` but obviously not possible...

Comment: @Swawa - what is `time` ?

Comment: @Swawa- I think best should be forget for times and insted use `timedeltas`